# Check if string contains a list of strings in any order

Tags: c#, string, linq, contains

Basically, I have a list of products and a search option. When multiple words are searched I want to return any product which contains all words searched in any order.

So if a user searches "green shirt", the returned list would include "green t-shirt large", "t-shirt green medium", etc. My (bad) code:

```
public List<Products> FindProductsByName(string query, int limit)
{
    string[] words = query.ToLower().Split(' ');
    List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        products.AddRange(All.Where(x => x.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(word)).Take(limit).ToList());
        //this will return all products which contains ANY word in the searched word list
    }
    return products;
}
```

So basically, I want

```
All.Where(x => x.Productname.ToLower().Contains(words[0]) && x.Productname.ToLower().Contains(words[1]) ...
```

but I don't know how many words will be in the search query. I feel like this should be easy but my brain isnt' working today. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you make a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)? The fiddle should be a working example.

Comment: Split both strings into a list of words; then sort both strings and run a *merge-comparison.

Comment: [Set operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx) article should help you to pick whatever operation on two sets fits your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a working solution before aloisdg posted his excellent solution. Here is my working code:

```
string[] words = query.ToLower().Split(' ');
var products = from p in All select p;
foreach (var word in words)
{
    products = products.Where(x => x.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(word));
}
return products.Take(limit).ToList();
```

I wanted to avoid breaking the product names into string arrays and using the intersect command because there are ~30,000 products in the table and this would slow things down.

Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: `var products = from p in All select p;` What are you doing here?

Comment: It is a good thing that you manage to solved your problem by yourself. I made a benchmark of our solution and mine is faster. if you need some perfs ...

Comment: var products = from p in All select p;

This line is setting up the query so we can add a where clause to it for each word in the array.

Comment: So your are using the deferred execution. ok.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the Linq method [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Working example on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQ8dG2).

**Code :**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = FindProductsByName("green shirt", 2);
    foreach (var products in list)
        Console.WriteLine(products.ProductName);
}

public static IEnumerable<Products> FindProductsByName(string query, int limit)
{
    string[] words = query.ToLower().Split(' ');
    List<Products> products = new List<Products>
    {
        new Products { ProductName = "green t-shirt large" },
        new Products { ProductName = "t-shirt green medium" },
        new Products { ProductName = "t-shirt red" }
    };
    return
        (from p in products
        let productsComponent = p.ProductName.Split(' ') // you should make a list of keyword in Products instead
        where productsComponent.Intersect(words).Any()
        select p).Take(limit);
}

public class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**Output :**

```
green t-shirt large
t-shirt green medium
```

Edit : I forgot to add the `limit`. So I added it.

Comment: Great example and this looks like it would work but I was able to solve this issue before you posted this. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. You can mark it as solved. have a nice day.

Comment: @tarnold86 perhaps to prevent others from downvoting this you should edit your question demonstrating the fix that you `Solved`

Comment: @MethodMan Done. And this got downvoted before anyone even commented, not sure why.

Comment: Yours is only faster because I was using the ToList() function. Also, your version was not running .ToLower() on the product list strings.

Update both to return IEnumerable and run it again. They are both very comparable.

Comment: Recheck. Damn I did think the only problem came from `ToList()`. I will remove my benchmark.

Comment: You have to be careful creating examples that won't translate well with Linq to SQL / EF.

Comment: @NetMage Do you have a better way to show off this feature?

Comment: The method @tarnold86 used in his answer is the best way in Linq to SQL that I am aware of - the translation only handles `Split` in the `select` and as long as the query words are small, you aren't sending too much to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ method `All`

```
products.Where(p=> words.All(w=> p.ProductName.Contains(w));
```

I took aloisdg [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KFVsKI) and updated with my answer.